# "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" issue java web project

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, include, mime

I have an issue on my dynamic web project.
The arborescence is

WebContent
|
|
bootstrap
css
js
WEB-INF
|
|
connection.jsp

Then in connection.jsp i make this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/connection.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/register.js">     </script>
<title>Jweb</title>
</head>
<body>
```

all css are not apply, and in the console on chrome i have this :

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
"http://localhost:8080/jweb/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css". localhost/:10
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:          "http://localhost:8080/jweb/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css". localhost/:9
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:    "http://localhost:8080/jweb/css/footer.css". localhost/:11
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:  "http://localhost:8080/jweb/css/header.css". localhost/:12
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:     "http://localhost:8080/jweb/js/jquery.js". localhost/:14
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/jweb/js/bootstrap.js". localhost/:15
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/jweb/css/connection.css".
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
 <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
 <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I try to solve this issue 2 days ago and I'm still on it.
Can you help me to solve it ?

Comment: Ok but I don't know where I have to setup this ? I tried to add <meta> with content-type set as "text/css" but not working. I tried to set the content type property into my servlet. and some other way to solve it (all solutions found in internet) but nobody working

Comment: Refer to your web server documentation. It depends on the server software.

Comment: tell us your server type (tomcat, glassfish, jboss) and Post your web.xml

Comment: @JérômeCampeaux I meant to post it on your question... not as an answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad i put it on my question

Comment: I used tomcat on my project

Comment: *"all css are not apply, and in the console on chrome i have this"* Note that those are probably unrelated issues. The warning message says it's interpreting the result as a stylesheet, so if the styles aren't being applied, there's probably a *different* problem responsible for that. But it would be best to deliver the stylesheets with the correct mime type in any case.

Comment: Ok but with the mime mapping it should be correct errors on chrome console no ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick "mime mapping web.xml" search suggests you'd use a `mime-mapping` element in your `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

E.g. (new lines right before the closing `</web-app>` line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
 <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
 <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks to reply. i made it but it still not working. Have i just to make this operation ?

Comment: @JérômeCampeaux: As far as I know that's all that should be required. You'll have to ensure that you restart the server, etc.

Comment: yes I'm sure, I restarted the server and in the developer view of chrome I can see the same issue of MIME

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample web.xml for you to try working with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
                    <jsp-file>index.jsp</jsp-file>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>

                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

                <jsp-config>
                    <jsp-property-group>
                        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
                        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
                    </jsp-property-group>
                </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I didn't use servlet mapping cause i used @WebServlet("/") on my servlets. If I make this I have an error for conflict between the description